# ¿Cómo mejorar consumo de la bateria por el uso de geolocalizacion en Android?

Tags: java, android, geolocalización, gps

Estoy usando geolocalización en android usando `GPS` y `NETWORK`, el ciclo lo tengo configurado cada 2 minutos envíe la ubicación, pero obviamente esto consume mucha batería, necesito alguna buena practica para que se envite estar enviar constantemente la ubicación si el usuario no sea movido.

```
TrackingModels.positionInfo position = new TrackingModels.positionInfo();
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

Location coordinatesGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location coordinatesNetwork = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Location coordinates;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es precisamente como lo comentas esperar cierto tiempo mientras se obtiene el valor de la "última ubicación conocida":

```
    Location coordinatesGPS = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Location coordinatesNetwork = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Por experiencia obtener la última posición conocida creo que 10 minutos es suficiente para una aplicación que no hace uso constante del GPS.

ahora se tiene [FusedLocation Provider Api](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) con la cual se puede optimizar aún más el consumo de batería, donde también se obtiene la última posición conocida mediante [getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi#public-methods)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo descargues el [ejemplo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/BasicLocationSample) de la documentación.